# Behavior of Observable.Subscribe when used with multiple IEnumerables

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I'm attempting to create an `IObservable<T>` from two arrays (`IEnumerable`s). I'm trying to avoid explicitly iterating over the arrays and calling `observer.OnNext`. I came across the [Observable.Subscribe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh229486(v=vs.103).aspx) extension method, which at first glance would appear to be what I need. However, it does not work as I expected to and I'm at a loss as to why.

The following code is an example:

```
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      var observable = Observable.Create<char>(observer =>
        {
          var firstBytes = new[] {'A'};
          var secondBytes = new[] {'Z', 'Y'};
          firstBytes.Subscribe(observer);
          secondBytes.Subscribe(observer);

          return Disposable.Empty;
        }
      );

      observable.Subscribe(b => Console.Write(b));
    }
  }
```

The output of this is "AZ", not "AZY" as I expected. Now, if I subscribe to `secondBytes` before `firstBytes`, the output is "ZAY"! This seems to suggest it is enumerating the two arrays in-step - which kind of explains the "AZ" output.

Anyhow, I'm at a complete loss as to why it behaves like this and would appreciate any insight people may be able to provide.

Comment: Still trying to figure out why this behaves the way it does, but in case you just need a fix: `return firstBytes.Concat(secondBytes).Subscribe(observer);`.

Comment: Just a small hint - if ever you find yourself returning `Disposable.Empty` then you are doing something wrong.

Comment: @Enigmativity - thanks for the advice - in this case, it's more a by-product of the simplicity of the example (or is there a more suitable return).

Comment: @cristobalito - Yes, you would return `new CompositeDisposable(firstBytes.Subscribe(observer), secondBytes.Subscribe(observer))`.

Comment: @Enigmativity nice one - thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for the lock-step iteration behaviour can be explained by the implementation of [Observable.Subscribe(IEnumerable source)](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/Rx.NET/blob/371c83c621562a2259580a03f0cb5bf8680ea720/Rx.NET/Source/System.Reactive.Linq/Reactive/Linq/QueryLanguage.Conversions.cs#L40) which uses a ["recursive" algorithm](http://www.introtorx.com/Content/v1.0.10621.0/15_SchedulingAndThreading.html#Recursion) which works by calling `e.MoveNext` in a scheduler action. If it is successful then the value is emitted and and the a *new scheduler action is then queued* to read the next value from the enumerable.

As you are subscribing to two enumerables and are not specifying any particular scheduler for the subscription, the default iteration scheduler will be used for these operations (defined by `SchedulerDefaults.Iteration`) which defaults to running on the current thread. This means that the enumeration actions will be queued up to run after your current subscription action completes.  This causes the enumeration actions to be interleaved - something like this

1. firstBytes.Subscribe() -> queue enumerate action
2. secondBytes.Subscribe() -> queue enumerate action
3. call firstBytes.MoveNext() -> OnNext("A") -> queue next enumeration action
4. call secondBytes.MoveNext() -> OnNext("Z") -> queue next enumeration action
5. call firstBytes.MoveNext() -> **OnCompleted()**
6. call secondBytes.MoveNext() -> OnNext(Y) -> queue next enumeration action
7. call secondBytes.MoveNext() -> OnCompleted()

The observer receives the OnCompleted() notification at step 5 so the remaining secondBytes enumeration steps are ignored.  If you had returned your subscription disposables then the second enumeration would have been cancelled at that point instead.

Comment: As it appears to have been missed in an answer below, but I think your question implies it, all you need is `firstBytes.Concat(secondBytes)`. While this will just give you an `IEnumerable<char>` you can still just subscribe to IEnumerables. If you really want, you can whack `.ToObservable()` on the end of it. But the `Observable.Create` in the OP is not necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Because you are subscribing to *two* observables, as opposed to a single observable that is the concatenation of two observables, there are two possible sources that can invoke the observer's `OnComplete` method. Since the first array is shorter, it completes after the first item is emitted, and the observer unsubscribes since it has received a completion notification.

The correct way to do this is to combine the two sequences into a single sequence, then subscribe to that:

```
var observable = Observable.Create<char>(observer =>
{
    var firstBytes = new[] { 'A' };
    var secondBytes = new[] { 'Z', 'Y' };

    return firstBytes.Concat(secondBytes).Subscribe(observer);
});

observable.Subscribe(Console.Write);
```

Comment: Makes sense - could have sworn I tried the Concat approach (in my more complicated use case). Thanks for the help.

Comment: Although - that `Concat` is an `IEnumerable.Concat`. In order to stay in `IObservable` land, it should probably be `firstBytes.ToObservable().Concat(secondBytes.ToObservable())`

Comment: @cristobalito It doesn't really make any difference functionally, at least in this case.

Comment: mmm, I wouldn't say "correct way to do it" The whole example in the OP is bogus and is Rx for Rx sake. It would be great to know why the OP wants to use Rx when the source is IEnumerable<T>?

Comment: Hi Lee - agree example is bogus but it was a simplified example compared to the problem I was trying to solve. In any case, I think you are correct and trying to shoe-horn the solution into Rx is not the way forward.

Comment: @LeeCampbell The correct way to subscribe to multiple sources in the `Create` function is to combine them in some way. Regarding `IEnumerable`, there are many situations where you need to produce an observable from an `IEnumerable`, examples being timed release of values, or retrieving values from a blocking enumerable in a background thread.

Comment: Where did the requirement to use Observable.Create come from? It is totally unnecessary